# How to get a const reference to an object and change the object using that reference (Using const_cast)?

Tags: c++, oop, const-cast

I have a member function returning a `const` reference to an instance of a class.

Example:

```
class State
{
  const City* city1;
public:
  State(const City& c) : city1(c) {}
  const City& getReference() const {return *city1;}
  void changeStuff();
};
```

How do I get a non-const `City *` pointing to city1 using const_cast and getReference()?

Also, by doing the following I was able to achieve what I wanted without using const_cast:
(Assuming there is already an instance of State called `state1`)

```
City ref = state1.getReference(); //Why does it work?
City * ptr = &ref; //This is what I wanted, but not this way
ref->changeStuff(); //How can I call functions changing things if the reference was constant?
```

How am I able to get a non-const reference from a function returning a const reference and even call setters?

Thanks for your attention

Comment: Why do you want a non-const pointer?  That seems to violate the entire purpose of constness.

Comment: I just want to ask the same question as templatetypedef too. If you want to 'hack' in, please explicitly clarify so people won't nag you by telling that your design is wrong.

Comment: This is a bit convoluted. First of all your `State` class isn't even valid C++ code (you're throwing a reference into a pointer in your ctor). However, more confusing is that `changeStuff` is a member of `State` but you want to call it with a `City` object (do both types happen the same method? why even mention it here?). Also, your `ref` variable is not a reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
City ref = state1.getReference(); //Why does it work?
```

It works because that's not a reference.  You're making a copy of the const value.  Try this:

```
City & ref = state1.getReference();
```

That won't work.  You can use const cast like this:

```
City * ptr = const_cast<City*>(&state1.getReference());
```

Just be sure that the object isn't really const.  Otherwise it's undefined behavior to actually try to modify it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have declared something is `const`, just like you make a promise to the compiler, you will never change the content in that thing, why would you want to do that?

If you really want to change something in the const type, you have to declare that `mutable`:

```
class A
{
public:
mutable int _change_me;
};
```

Now you can change the member `_change_me` even you have a const reference for `class A`.

Comment: This is not the case. The reference is constant, this does not necessarily mean the object it is referencing is constant as well.